# When run angular 8 production: Delete of an unqualified identifier in strict mode

Tags: javascript, angular

When I compile my angular8 (cli) project in production mode by

`ng build --aot=true  --prod --optimization=true --buildOptimizer=true`

then when I put `dist` to file serwer and open browser I get error in console and black screen:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Delete of an unqualified identifier in strict mode.
>   main-es2015.4c04714d1d600593094f.js:1

When I open `main-es...js` js file I see

```js
hasWebGL: function() {
    if (!window.WebGLRenderingContext)
        return 0;
    var e = document.createElement("canvas")
      , t = e.getContext("webgl2");
    return t ? 2 : (t = e.getContext("experimental-webgl2")) ? 2 : (t = e.getContext("webgl")) || (t = e.getContext("experimental-webgl")) ? 1 : 0
}(),

hasCursorLock: (p = document.createElement("canvas"), p.requestPointerLock || p.mozRequestPointerLock || p.webkitRequestPointerLock || p.msRequestPointerLock ? 1 : 0),

hasFullscreen: function() {
    var e = document.createElement("canvas");
    return (e.requestFullScreen || e.mozRequestFullScreen || e.msRequestFullscreen || e.webkitRequestFullScreen) && (-1 == s.indexOf("Safari") || l >= 10.1) ? 1 : 0
}(),

hasThreads: "undefined" != typeof SharedArrayBuffer,

hasWasm: "object" == typeof WebAssembly && "function" == typeof WebAssembly.validate && "function" == typeof WebAssembly.compile,
                   
hasWasmThreads: function() {
    if ("object" != typeof WebAssembly)
        return !1;
    if ("undefined" == typeof SharedArrayBuffer)
        return !1;
    var e = new WebAssembly.Memory({
        initial: 1,
        maximum: 1,
        shared: !0
    })
      , t = e.buffer instanceof SharedArrayBuffer;
    return delete e,t       // HERE IS PROBLEM !!!!!!!!
}()
```

Below I add package.json

```js
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 3002 --disable-host-check --poll 1",
    "build": "cp ./src/environments/environment.prod.ts ./src/environments/environment.ts && ng build --aot=true  --prod --optimization=true --buildOptimizer=true",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~8.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.800.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.0.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.9.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.3"
  }
}
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok - my mistake. In one of my angular project files I use imports of external libraries

```
import '../../../../assets/unity3d/Build/UnityLoader.js'; 
import '../../../../assets/unity3d/TemplateData/UnityProgress.js';

declare var UnityLoader : any;
declare var UnityProgress : any;
```

and forgot that angular insert them to build file `main-es20...js`. 
The angular force `strict mode` for that imported code and this cause error inside that libraries. When I remove that imports (but left `declare` statements) and link libraries in `<script ...>` tags inside `index.html` (where `strict mode` is off as default) everything works fine without any errors.